# QTextEdit - HTML / PlainText token cross-matching

Tags: html, qt, qt4, plaintext

Let me say first, that I have been stuck on this problem for several days. In a dialog, we have a *QTextEdit* with editable "tokens" (characters, or pair of characters). These tokens need to be *emphasized* and connected with a `QHash<int, MyType *>`.

In practice, this means, that parts of the text need to be emphasized and identifiable.

Example:

*Hello Doll **y** !*

---

So far, we have come up with a solution based on QTextEdit's implementation of HTML. After selecting the token with QTextCursor, the selected text would be deleted and replaced with *an anchor* with it's *href* attribute being the ID. Like so:

```
Hello doll<a href="1">y</a>!
```

Of course, the HTML insertion is not a problem. Neither the detection of the token inside the entire HTML. This standpoint runs into a wall at the moment you try to jump to a plain-text cursor location based on a location in the HTML.

---

The question is:

1. How do I get the plain-text positions of a token with a given ID
2. How do I get token's ID based on specific plain-text position

Any help would be much appreciated, even if it was a completely different solution compared to ours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a fan of the `QSyntaxHighlighter`.  I think it maybe an easier solution for this.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-richtext-syntaxhighlighter-example.html

If the usage of the highlighter doesn't match what you are looking for, I would look into using the Rich Text Processing of Qt.  It is made to do exactly what you are looking for and much more.  But the learning curve is a little steeper.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext.html

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/examples-richtext.html

Hope that helps.